# Is it possible to change a string into the name of an array that already exists

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have generated set of arrays called e_time, calc_time and p_time as well as arrays with the following strucutre e_hilat['pCO2'], calc_hilat['pCO2'], p_hilat['pCO2'] and so on and so forth for lolat and deep as well. I would like to plot time vs pCO2 for each box (hilat, lolat and deep) for each scenario (e, calc, p). However rather than copying and pasting each plot command I was wandering if there is a clever way to plot these using a for loop (or something similar). I tried concatonating "e_" and "hilat['pCO2']", however the result is a string not the array called e_hilat['pCO2'], is there any way to get the code to recognise the resulting string as the name of the array?

```
fig, axS = plt.subplot_mosaic([['a)', 'a)'], ['b)', 'b)']], figsize=(10, 10), sharex=True)

linestyle = ['-', '--', ':']

for i, box in enumerate([hilat, lolat, atmos]):
box\['colour'] = 'C'+str(i)

print(hilat['colour'])

for i, scenario in enumerate(['e_', 'calc_', 'p_']):
  for box in [hilat, lolat, atmos\]:
    axS\['a)'].plot(time, 'e_'+{box}['pCO2'], ls=linestyle[i], c=box['colour'], label='original')
```

This is my current code.

Please feel free to suggest any other possible method, the only really important part is that line colour used to plot each scenario is the same with respect to each box (i.e. so that plots of lolat are always blue) and that the linestyle for each scenario is the same (i.e. that ':' is used for calc).

Comment: Sounds like you'll want to use a dictionary instead of an array of arrays

Comment: Using identifier names like this is not at all how python was intended to be used. Rather if you want dynamically named lists and/or strings you can use a dictionary whose keys are these dynamic names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments suggest using dictionaries. For example, instead of an array named `e_hilat`, you could just have a dictionary called `e` with a key `hilat` where the array value is stored. That would give you this correspondence to your current values:

```
e = { 'hilat': e_hilat, 'lolat': e_lolat, 'deep': e_deep }
```

With similar dictionaries for `calc` and `p`. However, at this point I would be inclined to do the same thing for that axis, so it's all in one nested data structure:

```
data = { 'e': { 'hilat': e_hilat, 'lolat': e_lolat, 'deep': e_deep },
         'calc': { 'hilat': calc_hilat, 'lolat': calc_lolat, 'deep': calc_deep }, 
         'p': { 'hilat': p_hilat, 'lolat': p_lolat, 'deep': p_deep } }
```

Then you can get any value from e.g. `data[scenario][box]['pCO2']`. Or it might make more sense to rearrange it into `data[box][scenario]` instead; just depends on your situation.

To be clear, I wouldn't really construct it as you currently do in separate arrays and then build the dict using the above assignment; that's just showing the correspondence. I would instead put everything into the dict structure in the first place.